# Why does mkdir <path> fails in npm run in Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, cygwin, package.json

I am using Cygwin bash on windows. When I run `mkdir -p dist/ts` it works fine. But when the same is added to a script in `package.json` like

```
  "scripts": {
    "test1": "mkdir -p dist/ts "
  }
```

npm returns the following error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mmauricepinto\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test1"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-google-maps@0.16.0 test1: `mkdir -p dist/ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-google-maps@0.16.0 test1 script 'mkdir -p dist/ts'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-google-maps package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mkdir -p dist/ts
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-google-maps
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-google-maps
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\cygwin\home\mmauricepinto\Startup\angular2-google-maps\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: permission issues ?

Comment: package.json has 777 for all. Command works fine on direct run

Comment: Check the permission of directory. Probably, `npm` doesn't have enough permission to create the folder in that directory.

Comment: It is not a permission problem. It is a syntax problem. It is something with filesystem in windows where backslashes should be used when using mkdir. Check last paragraph of this article: https://www.windows-commandline.com/create-directory-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something with a filesystem in windows where backslashes should be used when using mkdir. Check last paragraph of this article: https://www.windows-commandline.com/create-directory-command-line

Use this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test1": "mkdir -p dist\\ts"
  }
```

You need to use two backslahes `\\` becouse it is interpreted as an escape sequence in this case.